# react json Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

I am using the React-Rails gem and accessing a json object `items` from a Rails controller.

Rails controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    render json: @items
  end
end
```

My React `App` component accesses these items and attempts to pass it as a prop to a child component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: {},
            activeTab: 'items'
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.getJSON('/items.json', (response) => { 
            this.setState({ items: response }) 
        });
    }

  render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ItemsContent items={this.state.items}> 
            </div>
        );
  }
}
```

And this child component looks like this:

```
class ItemsContent extends React.Component {
  render () {           
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Items: {this.props.items}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ItemsContent.propTypes = {
  items: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

And I get this error:

```
react.js?body=1:1324 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `ItemsContent`.
```

How do I get around this? Is there a way to easily use JSON objects in my React components?

Right now I tried wrapping the JSON object in an array:

```
            tabbedContent = <ItemsContent items={[this.state.items]}></ItemsContent>;
```

Comment: Are you trying to display all the items in this.props.items?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to display all the items!

Answer (score 0):

Since this.state.items is an array, you are unable to dump out all the items in an array like that. You can use the javascript array API and iterate over the items and display them like so :

```
class ItemsContent extends React.Component {
  render () {           
    return (
      <div>
        {
             this.props.items.map(function(item) {
                 return <div> Item : {item} </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ItemsContent.propTypes = {
  items: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

If you are only getting back a single object every time then map will not work and you need to break out the object by property in order to display everything :

```
render () {           
        return (
          <div>
              <div> Item : {this.props.items.a} , {this.props.items.b}, {this.props.items.c} </div>
          </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: But can you use map for a javascript object?

Comment: Is it just a single object that is being returned? Can you update your post with what the data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list in `render()` of `App` Component. And create a React.Component Item for each of the items.

`App.js`

```
render () {
        return (
            <div>
                this.state.items.map( function(item){
                   <Item value={item} key={}> 
                });
            </div>
        );
  }
```

In `Item.js`

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  render () {           
    return (
      <div>
         return <div> Item : {this.props.value} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Item.propTypes = {
  value: React.PropTypes.object
};
```